# onclick() event is not working in javascript and span tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written the below code to display textarea in the form but it is not working in javaascript. the real requirement is when i click on reply in span tag a text area with a button should appear but it is not happening. Is it happening because the script part is below the span tag or something else is the reason for it just asking.

```
  echo "<center>";
  echo "<span class=c20 id=like1>Like</span>";
  echo "<span class=c21 id=reply1 onclick='myFunction()'>Reply</span>";
  echo "<span class=c22 id=display1>Display</span>";
  echo "</center>";
  echo "<br><br>";
  echo "<span id=reply3></span>";
  echo "<br><br>";
```

'$row01["Email"]'; '$row01["Name"]'; '$row01["Message"]'; '$row01["Picture"]'; '$row01["Status"]'; '$replybymail'; '$replybyname'; '$row01["Password"]';

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("reply1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  reply();
}

function reply() {

var x = document.getElementById("reply3").value;
var email1 = document.getElementById("i1").value;
var pass1 = document.getElementById("i8").value;
var name1 = document.getElementById("i2").value;
var pict1 = document.getElementById("i4").value;
var status1 = document.getElementById("i5").value;
var message1 = document.getElementById("i3").value;
var replybymail1 = document.getElementById("i6").value;
var replybyname1 = document.getElementById("i7").value;
var email;
var picture;
var name;
var status;
var password;
var mess;
var replybymail;
var replybyname;

var url= 'profileto.php?email='+ email1+'&picture='+ pict1+'&name='+ name1+'&status=' + status1+'&password='+ pass1+'&mess=' + message1+'&replybymail='+ replybymail1 +'&replybyname='+ replybyname1+' ';

var forms = "<form id='replyform' method='POST' class='form1' onsubmit = 'myFunction2()'>
<center><textarea  cols='40' rows='50' class = 'c61' name='reply' style= 'height: 27px'></textarea></center><br>
<center><input  type='submit'  value ='Reply' class='c60'></center></form><br><br>";

 document.getElementById("reply3").innerHTML = forms;
      document.getElementById("replyform").action = url;

      if(x.style.display === "none" )
      {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
         x.style.display = "none";
      }
}

function myFunction2()
{
  alert("Your post is published");
}
</script>
```

Comment: (1) **Where** are the elements i1 , i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8 ?? (2) There is no point to have onclick='myFunction()' if you already use addEventListener("click", myFunction) on the element

Comment: Please edit your question instead of giving additional code as comment

Comment: Added the portion of code to main question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting the element to set OnClickListener
JS is not able to find the element!

You are not using inverted commas when set attribute value.

Change this line:

```
echo "<span class=c21 id=reply1 onclick='myFunction()'>Reply</span>";
```

To:

```
echo "<span class=\"c21\" id=\"reply1\" onclick='myFunction()'>Reply</span>";
```

`\` is used to escape `" OR '`.

Always add `\` before `" OR '`. Like this `\"`.

Not like this `"\`.

Comment: I added the \"\" in the span tag but it's still not showing results

Comment: Can u pls show ur full code? Edit ur question

Comment: The above mentioned is the full code

Comment: Your code is cutted off in between pls edit ur question and also you didn't started ur php script with its starting tag. Use PHP starting & ending tag

Comment: Use starting tag = `<?php` and ending tag = `?>`

Comment: This isn't ur full code
From where are you getting this array. `'$row01["Email"]'; '$row01["Name"]'; '$row01["Message"]'; '$row01["Picture"]'; '$row01["Status"]'; '$replybymail'; '$replybyname'; '$row01["Password"]';`. Where are the ID attributes `'i1', 'i2', 'i3'` etc

Comment: @user14026527 Did you get your problem solved or not?